# wordpress images not showing properly

Tags: images, media, cache, library

Images are not visible properly in the media library after caching them from my other website. [image]The featured image is also not being set. However the images are showing up on the front end of the website, and the path that it is being redirected is also correct. The images attached to the posts of the previous months are all showing up and i am able to set them as the featured image.

attached are the screenshots of the media library and the all post section.

Would really appreciate any insight on the problem.

Comment: What does "caching them from my other website" mean? Did the images move?

Comment: I have two websites with similar content. Exported the content (posts) of Site A to Site B and caching the images locally to SITE B's Server from Site A.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the **upload_path** **upload_url_path** under your admin options. I suspect they are still referencing the other website. Go to https://yourdomain.com/wp-admin/options.php and scroll down till you get to the the upload_path and upload_url_path.